# @Controller naming convention in SPRING

Tags: spring

I have

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/services")
public class ServiceController
```

coding here

My question is that... I need to replace

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/services/v1.0")
```

But I am getting the following exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found.
>   Cannot map 'serviceController' bean method  public
>   com.rrd.up2mews.json.ExpenseTrackerTransactionViewDetailsJson
>   com.rrd.up2mews.controller.ServiceController.getExpenseTrackerTransactionViewDetails(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,com.rrd.up2mews.json.ExpenseTrackerTransactionViewDetailsInputJson)
>   to
>   {[/services/v1.0/],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}:
>   There is already 'serviceController' bean method

How can i solve this

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've added second controller with the very same name (ServiceController) somewhere in context. Change one of them to something different.

@RequestMapping is only used to point spring which url this particular controller should serve.